# awk if statement checking multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, awk

I have a file like this:

```
1 1 9
2 2 4
3 2 5
4 2 4
```

I want awk to print unique records based on the second and third field. Both fields must be unique to be printed.

The ideal output would look like this:

```
1 1 9
2 2 4
3 2 5
```

So the record 4, because it is identical to record 2, is left out.

This is what I tried:

```
cat file | awk ' !($2 in array) && !($3 in barry) { array[$2]; barry[$3]; print}'
```

Running this command results in:

```
1 1 9
2 2 4
```

So it doesn't add record 3 because it's second field is identical to record 2's.

How would I go about coding so awk checks both values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do:

```
awk '!a[$2,$3]++' file
1 1 9
2 2 4
3 2 5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make an index with the 2 values and check it:

```
awk 'SEEN[ $2 " " $3 ] != 1 { print ; SEEN[ $2 " " $3 ] = 1 }' file
```